# How to get Youtube user history in Android?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Does anyone know how I can get the user's video history from an Android app? I've been searching but couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new YouTube Data API v3 you can get the following user playlists:

- uploaded videos
- favorite videos
- positively rated (liked) videos
- watch history
- watch later

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

And the following user activities too:

- favorite
- bulletin
- comment
- social
- upload
- playlistItem
- recommendation
- like
- subscription

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities

I wrote an article with a tutorial on how to use the YouTube API v3 Android, but is written in Spanish:

http://fuse21.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/utilizando-youtube-data-api-v3-desde.html

I believe that you can see the code changes and reuse them.

In the tutorial I made changes in the oficial sample tasks-android-sample ( this sample shows a list of tasks .. another service.. Tasks):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/?repo=samples

and I show how to reuse the app to get the list of the user YouTube activities.
I believe that with this tutorial you can understand how use the YouTube API in Android to get the "user history.."

Comment: how do you get those lists from youtube/v3/docs/playlists? I can't find the parameter that i need to pass to obtain watch history. can you explain it in detail? thanks

Comment: i find i actually have to get the playlist id from channel api, youtube/v3/channels, then i can query the playlists api by passing the playlistId in.

Comment: This controller performs most of those calls: https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/logged-in.js